# I am getting Memory ERROR when running this program

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

just met this question online trying to run it am getting memory error. any idea?

```
inputs= ['nodejs','reactjs','vuejs']
print(inputs)
for i in inputs:
    inputs.append(i.upper())
print(inputs)
```

Comment: I've removed the JavaScript tag, since it seems unrelated.

Comment: Don't modify a list or dict while iterating over it. Create a new list/dict instead.

Comment: This isn't related to Django either. I removed the tag.

Comment: You loop until you reach the last element of `inputs`. But since you add one element to `inputs` during each loop the loop will never end and the list keeps growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an infinite loop.
You should do this instead:

```
inputs= ['nodejs','reactjs','vuejs']
print(inputs)

upper_inputs = []
for i in inputs:
    upper_inputs.append(i.upper())

print(upper_inputs)
```

or even better:

```
inputs = ['nodejs','reactjs','vuejs']
print(inputs)

upper_inputs = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), inputs))
print(upper_inputs)
```